# How do you solve this quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics

The number of values of a for which
$$ (a^2 - 3a + 2)x^2 + (a^2-5a + 6)x + a^2-4 = 0$$
is an identity in x is?

Here's how much I was able to solve through:-

$$ (a^2 - 3a + 2)x^2 + (a^2-5a + 6)x + a^2-4 = 0$$

$$ ((a-1)(a-2))x^2 + ((a-3)(a-2))x + (a+2)(a-2) = 0$$

$$ (a-2)[(a-1)x^2 + (a-3)x + (a+2)] = 0$$

$$ so \hspace{5pt} (a-2) = 0 \hspace{5pt} or \hspace{5pt} [(a-1)x^2 + (a-3)x + (a+2)] = 0$$

$$ so \hspace{5pt} a = 2$$

$$ Now \hspace{5pt} [(a-1)x^2 + (a-3)x + (a+2)] = 0 $$

I don't know what to do next. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not use the quadratic formula?

Comment: While using the quadratic formula the determinant is coming to be -3a^2 +10a  + 17. Since the value of a is negative, the final answer will be an imaginary number

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a$. Is it a real number or integer? I assume it isn't complex because it sounds you want to exclude imaginary answers.

Comment: The textbook says that the answer is a = 2 and nothing else, so I am presuming the book is excluding the complex answers.

Comment: Read Mario's answer. a=2 is the only thingy that will give your expression as zero for all x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$(a-1)x^2+(a-3)x+a+2$$
is a quadratic polynomial, it has, at most, two roots, then $$(a^2 - 3a + 2)x^2 + (a^2-5a + 6)x + a^2-4 = 0$$
is an identity in $x$ only if $a=2$.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think I got the question til just now. Identity! For other values of $a$ the $(a^2 - 3a + 2)x^2 + (a^2-5a + 6)x + a^2-4 $ wouldn't be zero for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $Ax^2+Bx+C=ax^2+bx+c$ is an identity

$A=a,B=b,C=c$